# How to remove specific characters in a string that changes based on request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string

I have a string that looks like `` "{`index`:`20`,`value`:`RA`}<1" ``, and I want it to become `` "`RA`<1" ``. I don't think the replace function is sufficient as the index and value changes based on what I enter. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Note, the index, 20, value, and RA are wrapped in backticks in the string. I forgot doing that changes the appearance on stackoverflow

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.

Comment: Do the relative positions of `\`RA\`` and `<1` stay the same? I.e., is the part you want before `<1` always the thing between the last `:` and before the `}`? And the `<1` is always whatever is after the `}`? If so, it seems like it would be a simple matter of using `substring`, or possibly `slice`, and `indexOf`...

Comment: `RA` and `<1` also changes, and yes, the thing I want is always after the last `:` and after the `}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming the required string is everything after the last `:`, except for the `}`, the original string can be sliced and edited as follows:

```js
const string = "{`index`:`20`,`value`:`RA`}<1";

let newString = string.slice(string.lastIndexOf(":")+1).split("}").join("");

console.log(newString);
```

This will always append everything after the final `}` to everthing before it but after the last `:`, regardless of the earlier content.